# how to read a value from text HI file using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, file

I am new of python.

i want to read a value from the text file.

for example my text fileis

textfile

```
host="host"
dbname="dbname"
uname="uname"
pwd="pwd"
```

now i want to read these values from the file like below and use in the python script

host_name=host(host valuefrom text file )
same for all values.

how can we read a file and how to read value alone from the text file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not a good idea to save key, value pairs in a `.txt` file, `.json` is better format for the same and you can quite simply read the data into python dict as `json.loads("file_content")`

Comment: yes you are correct we are planning to use the same text file for shell scripts and python scripts. Now i want to know is there any way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate over the `.txt` file lines and check if the line is valid, by checking if `=` is present in the line and then simply `split()` the line to get the  key and value pair as:

```
kv_store = {}

with open("./file_path.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Strip any `\n` etc.
        line = line.strip()

        # Check if the line contains a key, value pair
        if len(line) > 0 and line.find("=") > 0:
            key, value = line.split("=", 1)
            kv_store[key] = value.strip('"')
print kv_store
```